# Determine web page draw time via a program

Tags: page-speed

Google Chrome has a nice tool to determine the time the page begins drawing, in the Network tab in Developer Tools. Similarly sites like webpagetest.org can tell you the draw time and give you the whole waterfall of page loads for a given web page.

I was wondering if I could automate the process of finding the time it took to the first page draw, for all of the pages on my site, so I can share this data within my company. Obviously the page draw time will depend on the latency and throughput of your connection, but I'm more concerned with the relative data about pages on our site. Can I get this data from Selenium or another tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could automate the process of finding the time to first page draw using WebPagetest.

From the webpagetest.org site:

> WebPagetest [...] was open-sourced in 2008 under a BSD license. The
>   platform is under active development by several companies and
>   community contributors on Google code. The software is also packaged
>   up periodically and available for download if you would like to run
>   your own instance.

http://www.webpagetest.org/about

Answer (score 0):

There is an SDK (software development kit) that lets you build an application around the page speed program to test your page load time. You can automate the process using this and some custom code

http://code.google.com/p/page-speed/wiki/DownloadPageSpeed